# ¿Cómo cambiar la dirección de registro de Bower?

Tags: bower

Al estar trabajando con un proyecto donde se gestiona las dependencias del front-end con *Bower* me percate que al instalar las dependencias con el comando `bower install` el proceso fallaba con el siguiente mensaje:

> bower angular#1.3.20 EINVRES Request to
>   https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular failed with 502

Al ingresar al sitio del mensaje se mostró el siguiente mensaje:

> This Bower version is deprecated. Please update it: `npm install -g`
>   `bower`. The new registry address is https://registry.bower.io

¿Cómo solucionar este error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solución

Actualizar tu versión de *Bower* utilizando:

```
npm install -g bower
```

O en caso de no poder realizar la actualización agregar o modificar el archivo `.bowerrc` que se encuentra en la raíz de tu proyecto y añadir lo siguiente:

```
{
  "registry": "https://registry.bower.io"
}
```

### Explicación

En la página oficial de *Bower* al buscar la documentación hasta el final encontré un *Tweet* indicando lo siguiente:

> Por favor actualiza Bower o configura .bowerrc de la siguiente manera:
>   https://gist.github.com/sheerun/c04d856a7a368bad2896ff0c4958cb00 … El
>   antiguo registro (http://bower.herokuapp.com ) esta obsoleto.

Explicación del autor:

> ¿Por qué dejar de usar la antigua url de registro? El dominio actual
>   del registro incluido en Bower (https://bower.herokuapp.com) pertenece
>   a Heroku. Significa que no tenemos control sobre él y que presenta al
>   menos dos desventajas importantes:
>
> 1. Dependemos de Heroku para alojar el registro (actualmente nos brindan amablemente créditos pero no podemos esperar para siempre)
> 2. No podemos cambiar el DNS de este dominio, por ejemplo, ponerlo detrás de CDN para reducir los costos y la latencia.
>
> Para solucionar esto, lanzamos parches para cada versión de Bower que
>   cambian la URL del registro a https://registry.bower.io. Es suficiente
>   actualizar.
>
> En caso de que alguien no pueda actualizar Bower (no recomendado), el
>   archivo .bowerrc presentado anteriormente debe agregarse a un
>   proyecto.

### Referencias

- https://twitter.com/bower/status/918073147789889536
- https://gist.github.com/sheerun/c04d856a7a368bad2896ff0c4958cb00
- [Explicación del autor](https://gist.github.com/sheerun/c04d856a7a368bad2896ff0c4958cb00#gistcomment-2226585)